# How to generate dynamic dropdown with json data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, dropdown

I have components for dropdown. I try to generate a dynamic dropdown using json data. But I can't do it. I share my following code of the components. I am new in react.
1st component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const DropDownInput = props =>(
    <option
        value={props.value}
        label={props.name}
    />

)

DropDownInput.PropTypes ={
    label: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

DropDownInput.defaultProps={
    option:'Select',
}

export default DropDownInput;
```

2nd component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import DropDownInput from "./DropDownInput";

const SelectDropDown = props => {
    return(

    <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <DropDownInput
            value={props.value}
            name={props.name}
        />

    </select>
    )
};

SelectDropDown.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.array.isRequired,

}

export default SelectDropDown;
```

3rd component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import TextInput from "./text-input";
import CheckedInput from "./checked-input";
import SelectDropDown from "./SelectDropDown";

const SubCategorySubmitForm = props => {
    return(

        <form onSubmit={props.submitHandler}>

            <SelectDropDown value={props.OptionValue} name={props.label}/>

            <TextInput
                name="subCategory"
                label="Enter Sub Category"
                placeholder="Enter Sub Category"
                value={props.values.subCategory}
                onChange={props.changeHandler}
            />

            <TextInput
                name="userid"
                label="Enter User Id"
                placeholder="User Id Enter"
                value={props.values.userid}
               // error={props.errors.userid}
                onChange={props.changeHandler}
            />

            <CheckedInput
                styleName="mt-2"
                checkBoxClassName="mx-2"
                label="All Information is Correct"
                name="isAgreement"
                value={props.values.isAgreement}
                checked= {props.isAgreement}
                onChange={props.handlerAgreement}
            />





            <Button
                variant="primary"

                type="submit"
                disabled={!props.isAgreement}
            >
                Submit
            </Button>

        </form>
    )
};

SubCategorySubmitForm.propTypes = {
    values: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
     label: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    changeHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    handlerAgreement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAgreement: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    OptionValue: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    //errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default SubCategorySubmitForm;
```

I have json data to generate the dropdown.
Last component:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {Card, Col, Container, Dropdown, Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import FormUp from "./fillup-form";
import Axios from "axios";
import DemoModal from "./DemoModal";
import {MdOutlineEditCalendar} from "react-icons/md";
import DropDownInput from "./DropDownInput";
import SubCategoryFormFillUp from "./SubCategoryFormFillUp";
import SubCategorySubmitForm from "./SubCategoryFormFillUp";


const FormValues={
    subCategory: '',
    userid: '',
}



class SubCategoryForm extends Component {
    state ={
        values: FormValues,
        DataList:[],
        isLoading:true,
        isError:false,
        isAgreement: true,
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get("/getMainCategoryByName").then((response)=>{
            if(response.status==200){
                this.setState({
                    DataList:response.data,
                    isLoading: false,

                });
                console.log(response.data)
            }
            else {
                this.setState({isLoading: false, isError:true})
            }
        }).catch((error)=>{
            this.setState({isLoading: false, isError:true})
        })
    }

    changeHandler = event =>{
        this.setState(
            {values :{
                    ... this.state.values,
                    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
                }}
        )};
    handlerAgreement = event =>{
        this.setState({
                isAgreement: event.target.checked,
            }
        )
        console.log('ss');
    };

    submitHandler=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

    }


    render() {
        const myList= this.state.DataList;
        const myView=myList.map(myList=>{
            return(<DropDownInput
                value={myList.id}
                name={myList.main_category_name}

            />);
        })
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Container fluid className="mt-5">
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={2}>
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={4}>
                            {Array.from({ length: 1 }).map((_, idx) => (
                                <Col>
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Body>
                                            <Card.Title><u>Main Category Setup</u></Card.Title>
                                            <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                                {myView}
                                            </select>

                                            <SubCategorySubmitForm
                                                values = {this.state.values}

                                                changeHandler={this.changeHandler}
                                                submitHandler={this.submitHandler}
                                                handlerAgreement={this.handlerAgreement}
                                                isAgreement={this.state.isAgreement}
                                                // OptionValue={myList.map(myList=>{myList.id})}
                                                OptionValue={myList.map(myList=>{myList.id})}
                                                label={myList.map(myList=>{myList.main_category_name})}

                                            />


                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                </Col>
                            ))}
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={6}>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default SubCategoryForm;
```

How to write the code to generate the dropdown with json data in my last component.

Comment: So many files and so many lines of code. You need to highlight which part of code is causing the problem

Comment: @brk in the last component:
<SubCategorySubmitForm/>